# Merge 2 request.get functions in one

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can i merge these 2 functions in 1? There are 2 api-s: /page1 and /page2. After that i want to merge the 2 arrays in one. I do this because github api shows only 100 objects per page in api.

```
request.get({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/angular/repos?per_page=100&page=1',
    json: true,
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
}, (err, res, data) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
} else {

    console.log(data.length);

}

});

request.get({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/angular/repos?per_page=100&page=2',
    json: true,
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
}, (err, res, data2) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Error:', err);
    } else if (res.statusCode !== 200) {
    console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);
} else {
     });
    console.log(data2.length);

}

});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call the second request after the first was finished, then use [array.concat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_concat_array.asp) method to merge both results:

```
request.get({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/angular/repos?per_page=100&page=1',
    json: true,
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
}, (err, res, data1) => {


    if (err) return console.log('Error:', err);

    if (res.statusCode !== 200) return console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);

    request.get({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/users/angular/repos?per_page=100&page=2',
        json: true,
        headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
    }, (err, res, data2) => {

        if (err) return console.log('Error:', err);

        if (res.statusCode !== 200) return console.log('Status:', res.statusCode);

        // merge 2 arrays:
        var data = data1.concat(data2);

    });

});
```

Comment: This has multiple issues.  It has no way of communicating back an error result from the second request and it runs the requests in sequence when they can be done in parallel (which gets results faster).

Comment: @jfriend00 I admit that your answer is great and should be accepted, but it requires adding another module `request-promise` and deep knowledge of promises `Promise.all()`, It's clear from the question that the OP does not understand how Async function works that's why I gave this simple response.

Comment: Anyone who is trying to coordinate multiple asynchronous operations should learn promises.  They are the supported way to handle asynchronous operations in Javascript now and in the future.  Just because it's a little more work to learn the right way to do things doesn't mean one should keep doing it the old way.  The worst part of what you show is that there's no way to communicate back errors in what you show and that's one of the primary benefits of promises.

Answer (score 1):

I would use promises to track when both requests are done and then execute the two requests in parallel (which gets faster results):

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

Promise.all([
    rp({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/users/angular/repos?per_page=100&page=1',
        json: true,
        headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
    }),
    rp({
        url: 'https://api.github.com/users/angular/repos?per_page=100&page=2',
        json: true,
        headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
    })
])).then(results => {
   let combined = results[0].concat(results[1]);
   // process combined results here
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Note that the `request-promise` library (which is just a wrapper on the `request` library) automatically checks for a 2xx status for you so you don't need that extra code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [async](https://github.com/caolan/async). It has powerful flow control ability.

Following code is how to use it to achieve your need. And [here](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#times) is document of `times`.

```
async.times(2, (n, next) => {
  request.get({
    url: 'https://api.github.com/users/angular/repos?per_page=100&page=' + n,
    json: true,
    headers: {'User-Agent': 'request'}
  }, (err, res, data) => {
    next(err, data)
  })
}, (err, datas) => {
  // here datas contains data of two request
  // and you could handle err at one place
})
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @Ics You just need flatten it. For example you could use `lodash.flatten` method or you could simply use `[].concat.apply([], datas)`

Comment: And you can use this way to request any more pages at same time.